# How does electrophoretic separation work in terms of separating soil into minerals?

Tags: reduction-potential, distillation

I found this diagram and would like to know how it works with soil.

Google searches yield protein/biology things, anyone know how this method would work with soil?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search term: "continuous particle electrophoresis" yielded much more results.

- **electrophoresis** - the movement of charged particles in a fluid or gel under the 
  influence of an electric field.

[image]
source: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNUgcq1M4LI

-

[image]
source: http://www.nature.com/articles/srep19911/figures/1

Heard some guy invented it while messing with some clay, but couldint find any video examples of that.